# Autorise computer accounts through AD group

Tags: sql-server-2012, security, active-directory

I would like to grant SQL access for computer accounts.
It works if I declare a login for each account, like `CREATE LOGIN [contoso.com\srv1$] FROM WINDOWS`

but I can't make it works when using a AD security group containing the computername.
Say SRV1 is member of contoso.com\server_group , and I create a login for it like this `CREATE LOGIN [contoso.com\server_group] FROM WINDOWS`
. Now, trying to request the DB with the computer account the following error is raised :
`Error get database Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'contoso.com\srv1$'."`

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! The issue occured because  we have set the group membership too early (before the computer login once to Active Directory). If we set group membership after a first login it is working as expected